# Tricky question about returns

Tags: risk, returns, log-returns

I have a list of monthly returns.
`-10% -20% -70% -30% -15% -60%`
The total end return is -94.859%. Because you calculate = 100 x (1+ -10%) x (1+ -20%) x ...

Now I want to know how much the two months -70% and -60% contributed to the end return. How can I calculate that?

The sum of all returns in the list is -205%.

The -70% and -60% entries adds up to -130%. Can I conclude that these both months stand for 63.4% of all losses? Because 130/205=0.634. If this is true, then these both months contributes 0.634 x -94.859% = -60.155% of the total end return. This means the rest of the months contributes (-94.859% - 60.155%) = -34.705% to the total end return. But I dont like this. It feels wrong. I guess the correct answer uses addition of log returns?

Do you have a better answer?

UPDATE: Alper below gives the answer in the comments. He writes:
if you have two returns -10% and -20%, then the total returns would be 72%. Each return gives a contribution like this: -10% gives a contribution of ln(100%-10%)/ln(72%) = 32% and -20% gives a contribution of ln(100%-20%)/ln(72%) = 68%. These numbers add up to 100%.

However, if the returns have opposite signs, say -10% and +20%, then this formula does not work.

Comment: My two cents. Compare the return of [-10% -20% -70% -30% -15% -60%] (which you already found) and the return of [-10% -20% 0% -30% -15% 0%] i.e. what it would have been if you had been spared the -70% and -60%. To me that is the "contribution".

Comment: I did two different lists [-60% -70%] and another list with the rest of the months. Then I calculate the end return for each list: the short list has an end return of -88% and the long list has an end return of -57.16%. If I multiply both numbers I get the end return of -94.589. But how much did each list end return contribute?

Comment: I dont understand your link. Do you have a clearer answer? :)

Comment: As described within the accepted answer to that question, use the logarithms of individual returns (ratios). Then divide each by logarithm of the cumulative return (ratio) to find the contribution of the individual returns. For example, if  there is neg. 10% and then neg. 20% return, individual contributions would be ln(0.9) / ln(0.72) and ln(0.8) / ln (0.72). Same methodology if you have both negative and positive monthly returns.

Comment: @Alper Thanx! Almost right! I notice a problem as I have both positive and negative returns in my real data. If I do like you suggest, it does not add up to 100%. How can I solve this when having both positive and negative returns? The positive returns have a ln(X) value which is positive. All other ln(X) values are negative. So it does not add up to 100%.

Comment: What do you mean? It can be proven mathematically that they will always add up to 1. Say you have -10% and +20% as monthly returns. Then you get ln(0.9) / ln(1.08) and ln(1.2) / ln(1.08) which would add up to 1. Signs of the contributions have to be different in this case because their contributions are the opposite

Comment: @Alper I mean that ln(0.9)/ln(1.08) = -1.37 and ln(1.2)/ln(1.08) = 2.37 which do add up to 100%. But I dont understand how much -10% and +20% contributes, from the numbers -1.37 and 2.37?

Comment: The individual contributions would be -137% and 237%, respectively, for -10% and +20%. Individual contributions are measured with respect to the cumulative return, and in this case, each happen to be larger than the cumulative return in absolute terms. Sorry, but there is no measure I know that provides otherwise useful results while guaranteeing each contribution to be below 100% and their total at 100%.

Comment: @Alper Thanx! Maybe you could take the absolute value? Anyway, I will count this as an answer. I would like to read more about this, do you have a formula or something to link to? If you write an Answer, I will give you the credits. :)

Comment: Perhaps the absolute is not a great idea, but it is your numbers. Not sure I really deserve credit for the answer and the question is already closed, so no worries!

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the initial 100 as the dollar value of a portfolio. As you mentioned, at each point in time, the 100 decreases by 10%, 20% ... 60%. Therefore, the portfolio value after each increase is:

| Time | Portfolio Value | % Returns | Dollar Value of Losses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100.0 | - | - |
| 1 | 90.00 | -10% | 10.00 |
| 2 | 72.00 | -20% | 18.00 |
| 3 | 21.60 | -70% | 50.40 |
| 4 | 15.12 | -30% | 6.480 |
| 5 | 12.85 | -15% | 2.270 |
| 6 | 5.140 | -60% | 7.710 |

As the the cumulative returns is 94.86, -70% and -60% contributed 58.11/94.86 = 61.26% and the rest contributed 36.75/94.86 = 38.74%. You can see both proportions sum to 61.26% + 38.74% = 100%.

Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Hmmm... I am a bit confused. If you switch places of -60% and -70% to other rows, then everything changes. Then the contribution is not 61.26%. It is different. Why is that?
(It is because you calculate the contribution via Dollar values. Not the percentage.)

Comment: Yes, that is normal, because percentage losses are dependent on the absolute value of a portfolio at the point in time. If -60% and -70% are the first two losses to occur (among the 6 losses), they would account for the majority of losses in the portfolio. However, no matter how you reorder your losses, the cumulative loss is always the same ~94.86.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought the point of percentage calculations, is to get rid of the absolute value? So, I am still confused. I would prefer to know how much both -60% and -70% contribute to the end result of -94.86%.

Comment: This is not very useful because the contribution of any return depends on its timing. There are better methods such as that described in [this Q&A](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/76158/47484).

Comment: It is written above in my original answer, "-70% and -60% contributed 58.11/94.86 = 61.26%". I don't think you can get the same contribution if you reorder the losses, it doesn't make sense. In your original question, you computed the total end return as the product of 100 and all the returns, but the losses from each percentage loss (-10%, -20%, etc) are order dependent. Hopefully this is better?

Comment: Pls review the answer in that Q&A carefully. It is not my answer but the contributions as measured by individual logarithms and therefore their ranks within the series are not order dependent. In addition, if you lose 10% and then 20% or 20% first and then 10%, you get the same cumulative return and therefore a method that calculates the same contribution for those respective returns in both cases makes more sense.

Comment: Ah yes, I agree the log method is better.